# IOS Check if m3u8 stream is connected

Tags: ios, testing, stream, m3u8

I use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play `m3u8` stream. But it doesn't support me a method to check if the `m3u8` link is working, so if the link is dead I must waiting for `MPMoviePlayerController` playing a while to make sure that it's not working. In this situation, I want to show an `AlertView` if the link is dead to keep user from not waiting before send the link to `MPMoviePlayerController`. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: You can use request timeout for this kind of checking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this once..

Normally we check this after some time, for that we can set a time delay

```
[self performSelector:@selector(movieTimedOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:20.f];

-(void)movieTimedOut
{
     if (!(self.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) || !(self.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK))
      {
           //AlertView
      }
}
```

Comment: This way need to waiting for delay time, is there any way that I can check immediately if the url is alive. Something like checking the internet connection of AFNetworking??